# How to separate TCP socket messages

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I've experimented a bit with async TCP socket messages between two programs, for passing data, numbers and/or text. What I've done is to use a keyword in the start of each message, and then seperate the values with the "|" character. So a message may look like this:

"DATA|490|40517.9328222222|1|6|11345|11347|11344|11345|106|40517.8494212963"

I set the read buffer size to 1024, as most of the messages will be within that length. However sometimes I may send rapidly many short messages where several together are less than 1024 characters, and it seems then it will be read in one go. And if I send a message longer than 1024 characters, it will be split. So I'm looking for some advice on how to handle this. Should I use some special characters to start and/or end each message? Would appreciate some tips on how you do this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to send the message length at the beginning of each message, serialized in such a way that it will work on little-endian and big-endian hardware.

This could help your receiver preallocate its receive buffer efficiently too.

Comment: Thanks! What you mean by serializing? Does it apply to standard Windows operated PCs? With your last comment, does it mean I should change the buffer size according to what message is received? How will this work.. Since the length of the message is not known until the message already has been read, I don't understand exactly what you mean.   Btw;  Is it any point to split up a message at the sender side, or will this not have any impact on performance?  Size will be a 50-character messages every 200ms, and rarely a 50,000-400,000 character msg.

Comment: Serializing just means "outputting as a string".  The suggestion from @terminus would be a reasonable way of doing this - convert the message length to a fixed-length string so it's easily converted back to an `unsigned int` on the receiving side.  You can request to read that many bytes first into a buffer of fixed size, and then allocate a buffer to receive the rest of the message.  Don't bother splitting the message on the send side - the TCP/IP stack will perform any required packetization.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to send the size of the message at the beginning of the packet. This way you'd know how much data to read. So it would look like:

```
00015MESSAGE|1|2 ...
```

It's important for the size field to have a fixed size.

You can also have this size field be binary, but it seems you are sending plain text so this way you'd have a humanly readable size field.

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches.

1. A length word prefixed to each message.
2. An STX/ETX-style wrapping of each message so you can see where it starts and finishes. This requires escaping of ETX bytes that occur in the data, and that in turn requires escaping of ESC bytes too.
3. A self-describing protocol, for example XML, or a type-length-value based protocol.

Comment: The OP already has to escape `|` characters that appear in the data, so this may not be such a burden.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol is everything. For my chat application I use the argument protocol like when you run

```
shutdown.exe -s -f -t 30
```

But then for sockets I use this

```
join John%20Doe            ' %20 for space
msg This%20Is%20a%20test   ' again %20 for space
```

This way it does not matter if your data is send ASYNC :D Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that problem by padding your messages with unique bytes (like 255 which doesn't appear in ASCII) to the buffer size and unpad them on the receiving end.
To me this isn't a very nice and smart fix, but it actually works.

Or you could try to send the overall packet length at the beginning of each package, which is a littile more challanging and works more efficiently as the padding technique when done right.
Merged packages would then look something like this (scheme):

```
05|.....02|..03|...
```

Answer (score 0):

The way TAR does it, is to use blocks of fixed size. Every block in TAR is 512 bytes, and the file (message) may be entirely contained within that one block. If it's not, the first 512 bytes includes a header that specifies how many additional blocks need to be read for that file (message).

Tar isn't a TCP app obviously, but it has similar data parsing or processing requirements.

Also Your size is smaller than 512 bytes, but maybe it makes sense to include a 64-byte block, or 128 or whatever, and ship all your data in packages of that size.  you lose efficiency with the overhead of the "box size", but you may gain in efficiency and simplicity of the data processing algorithm.